# Does Gradient flow of a distance function preserve geodesics (distance)?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, and for some $p,q\in M$, let $\gamma_{p,q}:[0,1]\to M$ be a constant speed minimizing geodesic with $\gamma(0)=p,\gamma(1)=q$. Consider the function $d_p(x):M\to \mathbb{R}^+$ defined by $d_p(x)=d_g(x,p)$ where $d_g$ is the distance induced by the Riemannian metric $g$, and consider the gradient flow of $-\nabla d_p$ denoted by $\phi_s$.

Now let $t\in(0,1)$ and fix $r>0$ small so that $d_p$ is smooth in $B_r(\gamma_{p,q}(t))$, if it is true that for $x,y\in B_r(\gamma_{p,q}(t))$ we have $\gamma_{\phi_s(x),\phi_s(y)}=\phi_s(\gamma_{x,y})$ (or if $d_g(\phi_s(x),\phi_s(y))=d_g(x,y)$?)for at least small $s>0$?

There are several conditions one could add to the manifold, like completeness, but I don't know if it is needed, so please add suitable conditions if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the example of Euclidean space? In that case, if $p$ is the origin, then $\phi_s$ contracts everything toward the origin at constant speed. Does that preserve distances?

Comment: @JackLee Thanks, you are right, and also the same happens on a sphere, everything is being contracted towards north pole at constant speed, which also doesn't preserve distance. I should have thought about some examples at first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper from Paul Ehrenfest which extends the manifold and its metric by one dimension in case some defines a function in it. The curve from A to B by action of the gradient flow is not geodesic preserving, but in this extended dimension, it is.